# Convert 2D array into list Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I have a 2D array and I want to convert into list.

My current code can convert into array:

```
z=[[0 for x in range(0,11)] for y in range(0,11)]

for y in range (0,11):
    x=0
    z[x][y]=((20-10)/10.0*y+10)
              
for y in range (0,11):
    x=10
    z[x][y]=((60-20)/10.0*y+20)

for y in range (0,11):
    for x in range (1, 11):
        z[x][y] = (((np.asarray(z[10][y])-np.asarray(z[0][y]))/10.0 + np.asarray(z[x-1][y])))

for y in range (0,11):
    for x in range (0, 11):
        print (z[x][y])
```

It outputs:

10.0
11.0
12.0
13.0
14.0
15.0
16.0
17.0
18.0
19.0
20.0
11.0
12.3
13.600000000000001
14.900000000000002
16.200000000000003
17.500000000000004
18.800000000000004
20.100000000000005
21.400000000000006
22.700000000000006
24.000000000000007
12.0
13.6
15.2
16.8
18.400000000000002
20.000000000000004
21.600000000000005
23.200000000000006
24.800000000000008
26.40000000000001
28.00000000000001
13.0
14.9
16.8
18.7
20.599999999999998
22.499999999999996
24.399999999999995
26.299999999999994
28.199999999999992
30.09999999999999
31.99999999999999
14.0
16.2
18.4
20.599999999999998
22.799999999999997
24.999999999999996
27.199999999999996
29.399999999999995
31.599999999999994
33.8
36.0
15.0
17.5
20.0
22.5
25.0
27.5
30.0
32.5
35.0
37.5
40.0
16.0
18.8
21.6
24.400000000000002
27.200000000000003
30.000000000000004
32.800000000000004
35.6
38.4
41.199999999999996
43.99999999999999
17.0
20.1
23.200000000000003
26.300000000000004
29.400000000000006
32.50000000000001
35.60000000000001
38.70000000000001
41.80000000000001
44.90000000000001
48.000000000000014
18.0
21.4
24.799999999999997
28.199999999999996
31.599999999999994
34.99999999999999
38.39999999999999
41.79999999999999
45.19999999999999
48.59999999999999
51.999999999999986
19.0
22.7
26.4
30.099999999999998
33.8
37.5
41.2
44.900000000000006
48.60000000000001
52.30000000000001
56.000000000000014
20.0
24.0
28.0
32.0
36.0
40.0
44.0
48.0
52.0
56.0
60.0

I want it to output into list like [[10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0], [11.0, 12.3, 13.600000000000001, 14.900000000000002, ...] ...]

Many thanks.

Comment: If the question is simply about formatting the output with `,` and `[]` symbols, you can see the array by passing **the array** directly to `print`. If the question is about getting all the slightly-off numbers like `13.600000000000001`, that is because of how floating-point numbers work; please see the linked duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I would like [] and , in my output.

Comment: Okay, so did you try `print(z)`?

Comment: I tried, and got no backets and commas:
for y in range (0,11):
    for x in range (0, 11):
        print (z[x][y])

Comment: Okay, so **did you try `print(z)`**?

Comment: you don't have a 2d-array. You have a *list*

Comment: it *sounds* like you want just `print(z)`.

Comment: Thank you, you are live saver. print (z) works, it gives brackets and commas